# Tomcat 7.0 timeout error when try to run in debug mode in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, timeout

when i am trying to run tomcat server in debug mode it is giving timeout everytime, but is working fine in normal mode, even i tried increasing the timeout duration in server and removed all the breakpoints from the project.. i tried various solution provided to similar issue in other posts but nothing is working anybody having idea how to fix that

Answer (score 10):

Figured out the reason. If we have too many breakpoints the debug mode takes strangely large amount of time. Disable all the breakpoints and start in debug mode when started enable the breakpoints as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure, but if I remember correctly the following property is enabled by default, disable it and try again: Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

here is something else that helped me. :)

on your eclipse properties add `-clean` to your target.  For example

```
..\eclipse.exe -clean
```